# Sum of all Hamming distances of a given string A from substrings of length |A| of another string B

Tags: string, algorithm, hamming-distance

Given two binary strings a and b, find the sum of the Hamming distances between a and all contiguous substrings of b of length |a|.

inputCopy:

> 01
>
> 00111

outputCopy:

> 3

Explanation: For the first sample case, there are four contiguous substrings of b of length |a|: "00", "01", "11", and "11". The distance between "01" and "00" is |0 - 0| + |1 - 0| = 1. The distance between "01" and "01" is |0 - 0| + |1 - 1| = 0. The distance between "01" and "11" is |0 - 1| + |1 - 1| = 1. Last distance counts twice, as there are two occurrences of string "11". The sum of these edit distances is 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 3.

In this question, i'm only thinking of a brute force solution with time complexity O(|a|.|b|) like a string matching algorithm... Is there any faster algo to do this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are computing the sum of Hamming distances, it can be done very fast:

```
H := sum of Hamming distances
compute array A and B such as the following:
    A[i]: the number of zeros up to i-th element of b
    B[i]: the number of ones up to i-th element of b

iterate over elements of a for i <- 0:|a|-1:
    as a[i] should be compared with all elemetns of b[i] .. b[|b|-|a|+i]
    its effect over the value of summing distances is:
        if a[i] == 0:
            H += B[|b|-|a|+i] - B[i-1]
        else: 
            H += A[|b|-|a|-1] - A[i-1]
```

In the above pesudocode `B[|b|-|a|+i] - B[i-1]` means number of ones between the `i`-th element and `|b|-|a|+i`-th element of `b` the same for `A[|b|-|a|-1] - A[i-1]`). These are elements that the `i`-th member of `a` should be compared with to compute the sum of Hamming distances. Hence, the times complexity of this algorithm is `\Theta(|a| + |b|)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in linear time and constant space.

Each bit in `a` will be compared with `|b| - |a| + 1` bits in `b`, and each mismatch will add 1 to the sum of all Hamming distances.

Furthermore, for each bit of `a`, we don't need to know the whole bit sequence that it will be compared to from `b`.  We only need to know how many zeros and how many ones it has.  As we move forward one bit in `a`, the corresponding range shifts forward by one bit in `b`, and we can easily update these counts in constant time.

Here's an implementation in python:

```py
def HammingSum(a,b):
    # compare initial range in b to first bit in a
    range0 = len(b)-len(a)+1
    numZeros = 0
    numOnes = 0
    for i in range(range0):
        if b[i]=='0':
            numZeros += 1
        else:
            numOnes += 1
    total = numOnes if a[0]=='0' else numZeros

    #adjust the range as we compare to the other bits

    for i in range(len(b)-range0):
        #count the bit we're adding to the end of the range
        if b[range0+i]=='0':
            numZeros += 1
        else:
            numOnes += 1

        #uncount the bit we remove from the start of the range
        if b[i]=='0':
            numZeros -= 1
        else:
            numOnes -= 1

        #compare range with bit in a
        total += numOnes if a[i+1]=='0' else numZeros

    return total
```